# Problem with google docs query and importrange

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-docs

I'm trying to import any row from the URL where column 1 contains the string 6293. When I execute this query all I get is the first row from the URL which does not contain the string 6293. BTW if I change the "where 1" clause to "where col1" I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
=query(importrange("URL","Cost Per SKU!a1:q1000"),"select * where 1 = '6293'")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Cost Per SKU!A1:Q1000"),
 "where Col1 = '6293'")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Cost Per SKU!A1:Q1000"),
 "where Col1 = 6293")
```

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: can you share copies of your sheets?

Comment: I got it to work. I didn't use uppercase C. Thanks